# connecting SQL Server 2005 to Eclipse

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, eclipse

i want to develop an android application that will use the (SQL Server database 2005). the database is already created in SQL server 2005. because i already use it in my website which implemented in C# (asp.NET framework). i.e the SQL server database is shared between both the websiite and the mobile application.

My Question is how can I access to the SQL server database using Ecipse?

I searched but I found that I have to create a web service first then connect it to the eclipse.. I think it is complex way and not practical enough:(

Can anyone help me using better way to connect the SQL Server 2005 database to Eclipse please?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

I think best way for this is create  Web [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API) that Connects to sql and return your response.

> The general concept of a web API (application programming interface)
>   has two main interpretations. It is used to refer to both a
>   server-side API upon a web server as well as client-side API within a
>   web browser.

http://www.asp.net/web-api